# Sessionization with spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bunch of events in spark (user clicks/actions/button presses) characterized by a `note` column:

```
>>> df.show(20)
+-------+-------------+------------+------+
|   user|    timestamp|        note|action|
+-------+-------------+------------+------+
|2376466|1458580817381|event #1 ...|UPDATE|
|2376466|1458580822034|event #1 ...|UPDATE|
|2376466|1458580822112|event #2 ...|UPDATE|
|2376466|1458580822166|event #2 ...|UPDATE|
|2376466|1458580822216|event #2 ...|UPDATE|
|2376466|1458580822225|event #2 ...|UPDATE|
|2376466|1458580822651|event #1 ...|UPDATE|
|2376466|1458580822660|event #1 ...|UPDATE|
+-------+-------------+------------+------+
```

I'd like to know the time duration of a "session" of particular `note`. For example, event #2 started at 1458580822112 and ended at 1458580822225, so the duration would be `..225 - ..112 = 113` msec. Is there any spark helpers or shortcuts to organize data into ""sessions" or some other way to extract the information like this? Or the idea is to keep adding additional state information to each row and rolling it up when an session identifier column is ready?

**NOTE: multiple notes of the same type should be considered to be separate sessions.**

Comment: As far as I understand your intentions it is possible with window functions but it is neither pretty or particularly efficient. Nevertheless I already posted some answer to the similar questions. In general it could be easier to implement something like this w RDDs (probably with Datasets as well) but it is quite broad question.

Comment: Do you mind digging up similar question to the surface?

Comment: I'll search tomorrow if I don't forget but it is pretty much a three basic steps: 1) identify switching between "sessions" (lag) 2) adding session identifier (cumulative sum over switch points) 3) some stats

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Spark-SQL to acheive your goal.
Here is some code that works for me which will give sessions.
You can write a helper function and then register it as UDF.
This UDF then can be called in your SQL statement.

```
df.registerTempTable("Events")    
import sqlContext.implicits._

# (You can modify this according to what exact value have in note column.)

def process(colname: String):String = {    
  return  colname.substring(0,8)    
}

sqlContext.udf.register("process",process _)    
val dd = sqlContext.sql("select timestamp as timestamp, process(note) as note from Events")

dd.registerTempTable("SubEvents")

val dt = sqlContext.sql("select last(timestamp) - first(timestamp) as session, note as note from SubEvents group by note")

dt.show()    
+--------+--------+    
|session|    note|    
+--------+--------+    
|       5|event #1|    
|       2|event #2|    
|       1|event #3|    
+--------+--------+
```

Also the complete bluemix spark notebook can be viewed [here](https://cdsx.ng.bluemix.net/data/notebooks/15920b0a-d10d-4474-a18d-bb5d547a5f88/view?access_token=a7f0f00cb48c0b36bf4b98f3308585d38cb3e6b71f84cebec12ca473f7fd43d4):-

Thanks,

Charles.

Comment: This is helpful, but it will lump all sessions into one and determine `min` and `max` timing for all events. I want to keep multiple consecutive events as one "session"

Comment: So you want to group by user?

Comment: I want to group by note, but multiple notes should be parted into separate sessions.

Comment: You can do that in the process function but I wonder what is the factor that decide which parts belong to one session